# How to restore Unix terminal

Tags: mac, bash, unix, terminal

Some times my Unix terminal gets destroyed, either by:

- I can type commands, but characters are not echoed on the screen. When I press enter, the prompt is printed on the same line as the current one (newline is not inserted first)
- If I accidentally do `cat` on a binary file, then the charset is changed so that commands I type are shown as garble rather than normal ascii.

Is there any fix-all-way to restore the shell back to normal, or do I just have to close the terminal and start a new one?

(I am on Mac with Bash at the moment, but I've had this on other systems too.)

Answer (score 2):

Type :

```
kill -28 $$
```

or

```
reset
```

that should restore your term =)

### Note

`28` is  *SIGWINCH* signal, see

```
man 7 signal
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to unwedge a tty is to type: `^Jreset^J` (here `^J` is control-J). This sends a newline to finish any line (first `^J`), the command `reset` and another newline. If whatever is listening is a shell, this should fix things. Sometimes (rarely) replacing the command with `stty sane` is required. If you know what might be running behind it, perhaps sending whatever command makes that quit is needed beforehand.